# Bootstrap JS Modal loading but not editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I used JavaScript to load Bootstrap Modal, `$('#myModaltictacgame').modal();` with a `HTML Form` with `input` details in `table` so my modal code looks like this

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
 <!-- Modal content-->
  <div class="modal-content">
   <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;      </button>
            <span>my modal</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body table-responsive">
        <table...>    
         <form ....>
           <input ...>
            ...
        </form>
        </table>
       </div>..
        ..
 </div>
```

So when I use select option Modal window should be open which is fine and showing all the input fields but its coming with a transparent black window, every thing on modal is visible but I can't select of input any detail, unless I open inspect element window on bottom of my browser so on top of inspect window coming with 2 inches gap to select my normal page, hard to explain but please check the attached pictures [capture screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZO62.jpg), [capture screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a70Lg.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML structure should follow the structure as mentioned in the [**Bootstrap Document**](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples)

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>            
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        //put your stuff inside the modal-body div
        <form ....>
        <table...>
        <input ...>
          ...
        </table>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Comment: I followed the same structure, sorry I should had more clear in my question, except `form` started inside `table`